# Allow community-users to create employees for multiple accounts

Tags: community, sharing

In our community we would like for one contact (community user) to be able to view and create employees for multiple related accounts accounts. I have already figured out how to make all related accounts with employees visible to the user, though they still can only create employees for the account with the direct relation.

Does anyone know a way to make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your contact can be related to one or more accounts, the assumption is that the org has **Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts** settings enabled in Setup/Account Settings.

Use community sharing sets to define record access rights for your community users using account relationship based criteria.

1. Navigate to Setup, (quick find) Communities Settings
2. Scroll down to the Sharing Sets area
3. Create or edit an existing sharing sets
4. Ensure the community user profiles are selected under Applies to Profiles
5. Select Employee from Available objects
6. Configure the access for Employee (Edit/Set up)

   - Grant access where User: **Contact.RelatedAccount**
   - Matches Target Employee: **AccountId (lookup to account)**
   - Access Level: **Read/Write**

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!